# Download the older version git for windows

Tags: windows, git

How can I download the git 2.24.1 exe for windows from this [link](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/), but I'm not actually sure what to do with them to install.

Comment: That looks like Linux software, not Windows software.

Answer (score 7):

Never mind. Found it here the Git old version
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.24.1.windows.2